# Renaming all the folder names in the current dir that has files and sub directories inside using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a set of folders like below, which has files and subfolders inside them, i want to rename
all the smv2103* folders to smv2106* folders , keeping the files and subfolders inside them intact using Powershell

```
E:\online\smv2103pdf
E:\online\smv2103mac
E:\online\smv2103frp
E:\online\smv2103rep
E:\online\smv2103soc
E:\online\smv2103bid
E:\online\smv2103rem
E:\online\smv2103nop
E:\online\smv2103gac
E:\online\smv2103pam
```

Any help would be highly appreciated , as Rename-Item itself is not working because of the files and subfolders inside

```
Get-ChildItem "E:\online\*"  -Directory| 
 Where{  ( $_.Name -like "*2103*") } |
 ForEach-Object{
        ((Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) -replace "2103","2106") | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
      }
```

Comment: What do you mean `Rename-Item` is not working? Why?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Get-ChildItem "E:\online\*"  -Directory| 
     Where{  ( $_.Name -like "*2103*") } |
     ForEach-Object{
            ((Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) -replace "2103","2106") | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
          }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want to rename the folders? You use `Get-Content` to get the content from within files. To *filter* for a certain criteria, `Get-ChildItem` has a `-Filter` Parameter you can use.

- `Get-ChildItem -Filter "*2013*"`

When filtering in powershell, its good practice filtering as far left as possible. Now, knowing your just looking to rename the folders themselves, we can remove `Get-Content` and pipe the info onto `Rename-Item`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\online*" -Filter "*2013*" -Directory | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $_.Name.Replace('2013','2016') 
    }
```